# How to get facebook share count of a particular url.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the url i shared twice in facebook
http://dev.woofyz.com/status/dexter/467 and ithis is the api i am using 
http://graph.facebook.com/http://dev.woofyz.com/status/dexter/467 but it is returning only id not share

Answer (score 0):

The proper link for it would be

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/http://dev.woofyz.com/status/dexter/467%22

but you will have to provide an access token to view it, if you want to see an example use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and enter your link with a generated access code.

You'll see an object like this

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "888000351256371",
    "title": "Video Youtube post",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-03-12T13:11:33+0000",
    "url": "http://dev.woofyz.com/status/dexter/467"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 2
  },
  "id": "http://dev.woofyz.com/status/dexter/467""
}
```

Comment: access token of current user logged in then it will give share count of that user. How to get total share count.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/url

The right call would be

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token={access_token}&id=http://dev.woofyz.com/status/dexter/467
```

where `{access_token}` can be any Access Token.

Comment: access_token will give share count by that user. I want total share count

Comment: @RupaDas: That’s nonsense, there _is_ no share count “by user”. The result you are seeing is how often that URL has been shared, _globally_.

Comment: how to get access_token which will be valid everytime because once a user logged out access_token changes.

Comment: Use an App Access Token. Simple as that